# iSpazz 64-bit problem?

Tags: itunes

So there is this iTunes Plugin I wanna install called [iSpazz](http://www.keindesign.de/stefan/Web/Sites/iWeb/Site/iSpazz.html) that makes your keyboard backlight flash to the music from iTunes I dragged the file that I downloaded into the iTunes plugin folder and iTunes doesn't load up because the plugin is designated for 32-bit versions of iTunes so I right click on the iTunes app and set it so that it runs on 32-bit mode. It doesn't let me open iTunes and gives me this error [image: error message]

> iTunes 12.1.0.50
>
> MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014) 2.6 GHz Intel Core i5 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 Intel Iris 1536 MB

Comment: What version of OSX?

Comment: one of it is you need to download the older version of ITUNES.
but i wont do that just for backlit because the older version is sucks and confuse to use if you have the El Capitan or latest version of Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you're stuck.

iTunes will only run in 64-bit mode Since v11 on Mavericks.

That plugin is from 2007, before 64-bit iTunes was even thought of.

Ne'er the twain shall meet, unfortunately.